# Creating folder,files using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with node.js and looking for some examples and best practices around:

1. Creating a folder named test_folder
2. Adding a new file to that folder, named test.txt
3. Adding the text `HI` to test.txt

Comment: And what is your question? What is the problem you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following is the code to create a folder and then create a file inside it with some text.

```
let fs = require('fs');
let dir = './test_folder';    //name of the directory/folder

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){    //check if folder already exists
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);    //creating folder
}

fs.writeFile("./test_folder/test.txt", "HI", function(err) {    //creating file test.txt inside test_folder with HI written on it
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file is saved!");
});
```